# KendoUI compued observable

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mvvm

When `this.get('name')` is used in a computed observable calling that computed observable results in the error `this.get is not a function`.

Example: https://dojo.telerik.com/aXupaPog

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript `this` is referes to diffrent objects depending on how a function is called. In your example you are receiving function from view model and then execute it.

```
 var v = viewModel.get('v')();
```

In that case `this` inside function is referes to 'Window' object. To avoid this error you should call function as viewModel member.

```
 var v = viewModel.v();
```

or manually set `this` to viewModel via bind/apply/call methods.

```
 var v = viewModel.get('v').call(viewModel);
```